# How to support multiple grant requests coming from different clients to single authorization server?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

We have an authorization server, which is used by multiple clients.
Few clients wants to generate the access token using "client_credentials" grant type(thus sharing the clientId and clientSecret in the /token endpoint), while few using "authorization_code" grant type to generate the auth code(/authorize) and subsequently access token(passing the auth code in /token endpoint).
How do I configure this?

```
authorizationServerConfigurer
                .oidc(oidc -> oidc
                        .providerConfigurationEndpoint(providerConfigurationEndpoint ->
                                providerConfigurationEndpoint.providerConfigurationCustomizer(builder ->
                                        builder
                                                .grantTypes(grantTypesList)
                                            .tokenEndpointAuthenticationMethod("client_secret_post")

                                ))
                )
                .authorizationEndpoint(authEndpoint ->
                        authEndpoint
                                .authorizationRequestConverter(new AuthorizationRequestConverter())
                )
                .tokenEndpoint(//support authorization_code)
                .tokenEndpoint(//support client_credentials)

                ;
```

I have tried to find documentation to support this, but couldnt find a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide multiple `RegisteredClient`s through a `RegisteredClientRepository`.

This is well documented in the [Getting Started example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#registered-client-repository), which only configures a single client, but you can also configure multiple. See the demo sample which also provides an [example of multiple clients](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/7c197164e95395ff71ec03c191ee0ab655affdf2/samples/demo-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L136-L160). More details about `RegisteredClientRepository` are provided in [core components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#registered-client-repository) in the docs.

Comment: Hello Steve. I don't think this will resolve my issue. If I have to use different request token request converter on the basis grant type, for example consider following scenario:
1. Client "1": /token body{clientID,clientSecret, metadata}
2. Client "2": /token body{authcode, metadata}

so, how does the token endpoint support multiple contracts?

Comment: The token endpoint comes pre-configured for multiple grant types. You don't need to configure anything unless you're configuring a custom or extension grant type that is not supported [out of the box](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#feature-list).

The pre-configured client authentication methods also support multiple types out of the box. So please check the documentation for this, as it is all very well documented.